# Node.js permission denied public key

Tags: node.js, ssh, npm

I'm trying to run a Git command via node over SSH but I keep getting the error:

> Permission denied (publickey)

I guess this is because Node does not have access to my SSH keys since it is running in a child process?

How can I get past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, if your credentials are correct then it should work.
I guess you are running something like this -

```
require('child_process').spawn('git', ['push', 'origin', 'master']);
```

It works for me in both cases, ssh and https.

Comment: prob working for you coz you are using .spawn() instead of .exec() ??? i am however using an npm script to kick it off ... also i had another problem, my key was not called the default id_rsa which I think node is looking for ... thanks for the feedback

Comment: the fix that worked for me is below but my solution was warped somewhat due to the twisted nature of my setup! I think this solution is probably the out of the box solution - accepted

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this running a Bash script from node as follows:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "npm-run-all -p server update",
  "server": "dyson rest 7070",
  "update": "sh update.sh"
}
```

`update.sh` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -o pipefail

SSH_KEY=/path/.ssh/id_rsa

function update {
  eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  ssh-add ${SSH_KEY}
  git submodule update --recursive --remote
}

update
```

The main thing is to start the `ssh-agent` in Node and then add your ssh key to the agent before running your `git` command.

UPDATE: The above works but I found a better answer. The reason it was failing is because inside the executing script the HOME environment variable was not pointing to the same HOME when outside the script. I fixed this by putting my ssh keys in both HOME folders. Then the script was able to find the right key and voilà.

PS You can determine the value of the HOME variable in Node by logging `process.env.HOME` or in a shell script with `echo "${HOME}"`.